# How to find if a function as only one root

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, fixed-point-theorems, numerical-calculus

I want to know if my solution for this problem is correct or if I am doing anything wrong.

I have to prove that the equation $2+\frac{x}{2}+\ln(x)=0$ has a solution in the intervall $I=\left(0, \tfrac{1}{e}\right)$.

so I have to test if the function $f(x) =2+\frac{x}{2}+\ln(x) $ has a root in $I$.

With $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=- \infty$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow \tfrac{1}{e}}f(x)=\left(1+\tfrac{1}{2e}\right)>0$
We see that the function has at least one root.

With the first derivative $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{x}$ we see that, since the first derivative is positive and monotonically decreasing in $I$, the function has only one root. (The function can only go up since there is no point where the slope becomes negative).

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: If you want to make it more rigorous, use Rolle’s Theorem.

Comment: @Wintermute Can you double-check that you read the equation correctly? I get a zero at  $0.127$

Comment: Oops, my mistake! Comment deleted. Why not just say $f(0.1)=-0.2525$ and $f(0.3)=0.946$. Since $f$ is continuous, by the I.V.T. we have a root on the given interval.

Comment: You can avoid the limits by saying $f(e^{-3/2})>2+0-\frac32>0$  and $f(e^{-4})<2+1-4<0$ so with continuity and completeness there is a root between them (intermediate value theorem) and then use your positive first derivative argument to say it must be unique.